# How to link a view to a model in vb.net code First

Tags: vb.net, ef-code-first, edmx

I've an old programm with edmx. Inside this one, I've linked a class (Table) To a View (Table/filter on a value of a column)
I want migrate this project to code first.
I copy/paste the project delete edmx file and generate models from an existing database.
All is good except this link.

```
<Table("JoinAffectation")>
partial public Class JointAffectation
 public property Id as Long
 public IdRecherche as Integer 'the link with my view
 <NotMapped>
 <ForeignKey("Id")>
 PUBLIC OVERRIDABLE PROperty RechercheJoint as ViewRechercheJoint
```

But When I try to use function of automatical sort/filter using expression
I've error : The specified type member 'RechercheJoint' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

If I removed   I error saying I don't same comumn and property... Also , How Can I stipulate RechercheJoint is mapped on IdRecherche

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Using modelbuilder, I can join my view and my table like in edmx

```
<Table("JointAffectation")>
Partial Public Class JointAffectation
  Public Property Id As Long
  Public Property IdTypeJoint As Long
  Public Property IdRecherche As Integer
  Public Overridable Property JointType As JointType

  <ForeignKey("Id")>
  Public Overridable Property RechercheJoint As ViewRechercheJoint

End Class

<Table("ViewRechercheJoint")>
Partial Public Class ViewRechercheJoint
  <Key>
  <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
  Public Property Id As Integer

  <StringLength(50)>
  Public Property Libelle As String

  <ForeignKey("IdRecherche")>
  Public Overridable Property JointAffectations As ICollection(Of JointAffectation)

End Class 

modelBuilder.Entity(Of JointAffectation)() _
        .HasRequired(Function(e) e.RechercheJoint) _
        .WithMany(Function(e) e.JointAffectations) _
        .HasForeignKey(Function(e) e.IdRecherche)
```